# ios8 modifying system keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, keyboard

i'm fairly new to programming. i want to modify the decimal pad system keyboard so that when a user selects a particular text field, a decimal keyboard will appear.  i don't want the alphabet characters that are present in the current system keyboard but otherwise they keyboard will be the same.  i don't want to use an extension for a completely new keyboard as i know that will require a way to change keyboards for the user which i absolutely don't want.  i just want a minor tweak of the apple decimal keyboard.  from what i have researched so far i was led to custom views and input accessory views for data input in the apple documentation.  however, this documentation is in objective c which i am not familiar with.  just wondering what the best way would be to embark on this.  thank you very much.

Comment: so far what i have done is created a new UITextField subclass for the selected field.  in that subclass i have overridden the inputView property with getter and setter.  It seems to be working but not sure if this was the best method to do this.  i will post my code below as soon as i figure out how to post code!  i am very new to this...

Comment: You can set the keyboard type property in Storyvoard for a text field. Set that property to number pad. It will display the number pad without alphabets. I am not sure why you have written that you want to modify decimal keyboard.

Comment: hi Jassi.  thanks for your reply.  unfortunately number pad does not have the decimal so that will not work for me.  i need the decimal keyboard which is why i mentioned that above.  i guess i should have said decimal pad to be explicit.  thanks

Comment: There is a decimal pad also. Use that, you can set that from storyboard or XIB or from code. 

   ` [self.tfPassword setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];`

Comment: the decimal pad in storyboard includes the letters on the key which is the whole problem i was trying to avoid.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
```

Here is my code.  It seems to work but I'm not sure if it's the most efficient solution.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.  Pardon the pun!

```
class myTextField: UITextField {

    override var inputView: UIView! {
        get {var myView = getMyKeyboardView()
            return myView}
        set {}
    }

    func getMyKeyboardView() -> UIView! {
        var myKeyboardView: UIView!
        var keyboardNib = UINib(nibName: "myKeyboard", bundle: nil)
        myKeyboardView = keyboardNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as UIView
        return myKeyboardView
    }
```